# Couldn't find cube root limit $\lim_{x\to1}{\frac{\sqrt[3]{x-1}}{\sqrt{x}-1}}$ with conjugate.

Tags: limits, radicals

I tried to multiply by the conjugate but couldn't get anything.

$$\lim_{x\to1}{\frac{\sqrt[3]{x-1}}{\sqrt{x}-1}}$$

Comment: why this equation haven't seen as a normal equation

Comment: You need to put dollar signs round your equation.

Comment: You could multiply and divide by not only $\sqrt{x}-1$, but also by $\sqrt[3]{(x-1)^2}$. The expression becomes $\frac{x-1}{x-1}\frac{\sqrt{x}+1}{\sqrt[3]{(x-1)^2}}$ near $x=1$.

Comment: @GamarMustafa To avoid downvoting and request for closure you should indicate the full details of your attempt to solve it with conjugate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Let $y^3=x-1\to 0$ then consider

$$\frac{y}{\sqrt {y^3+1}-1}= \frac{y (\sqrt {y^3+1}+1)}{y^3}$$

Comment: so the answer is infinity?

Comment: Yes it seems so!

Comment: thanks a lot))))

Comment: You are welcome! Try also to solve in different ways according to other suggestions! It’s a good exercise. Bye

Comment: Note also that the change of variable $y^3=x-1$ is fine because it keep the sign of the original expression. That’s a crucial fact to operate the change of variable properly.

Answer (score 2):

Option :

$y=\sqrt x$; $y \rightarrow 1$;

$\dfrac{(y^2-1)^{1/3}}{y-1}=$

$\dfrac{(y-1)^{1/3}(y+1)^{1/3}}{(y-1)^{1/3}((y-1)^{1/3})^2}=$

$ \dfrac {(y+1)^{1/3}}{((y-1)^{1/3})^2}.$

Answer (score 1):

Hint

Let $\sqrt x=y,x=y^2$ to find

$$\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{y^2-1}}{y-1}=\sqrt[3]{y+1}\cdot\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{y-1}{(y-1)^3}}$$